# Fourier Transform for fourth order PDE (transverse displacement in elastic bar).

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convolution, fourier-transform

I'm trying to solve this problem from a textbook:

> The transverse displalcement in an elastic bar is given by
>
> $\dfrac{\partial^4w}{\partial x^4}+\dfrac{\partial^2w}{\partial
> t^2}=0 \tag{1}$
>
> $-\infty < x < \infty$, $t > 0$
>
> with initial conditions
>
> $w(x,0)=f(x)$
>
> $w_{t}(x,0)=0$
>
> Using Fourier Transforms and convolution, show that the solution is
>   given by $$  w(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{1/2}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{(x-u)^2}{4t} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)f(u)\
> du$$

Using this definition of the Fourier Transform:
$$\mathcal{F}[f(t)](k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i k t} \, dt. $$

I'm guessing that the standard approach to this question is taking FT of both sides of $(1)$ but I'm not sure how to begin this. If the FT is defined as an integral of $dt$, how would I represent the FT of a fourth order partial derivative with respect to a different variable (in this case, $x$)?

Some tips with the convolution would also help greatly! Thanks.

EDIT:
If my intuition is correct, equation $(1)$, after FT, should take the form

$\dfrac{\partial^4w}{\partial x^4} - k^2\bar W = 0$

but this doesn't seem easy to solve either.

IC: $w_{t}(0,x)=0$ changed to $w_{t}(x,0)=0$

Answer (score 3):

Taking Fourier transforms (in the $x$ variable) we get
$$
\frac{d^2\hat w}{dt^2}+k^4\,\hat w=0,\quad \hat w(0)=\hat f(k),\quad\frac{d\hat w}{dt}(0)=0.
$$
The solution is $$
\hat w(k,t)=\cos(k^2t)\,\hat f(k).
$$
Finally, 
$$
\mathcal F^{-1}\bigl(\cos(k^2)\bigr)(x)=\frac12\Bigl(\cos\frac{x^2}{4}+\sin\frac{x^2}{4}\Bigr)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\cos\Bigl(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When you take the inverse Fourier Transform of $cos(k^2)$, what happens to the $t$ from $\hat w(k,t)$?

Comment: It is the behaviour of the Fourier transform under dilations. If $f_t(x)=\dfrac1t\,f\Bigl(\dfrac{x}{t}\Bigr)$, then $\widehat{f_t}(k)=\hat f(t\,k)$.